# How to give named tupple for the accumulator of the aggregate function?

Tags: c#

I have a list of Points. And I want to get the nearest point of another point (origin) of this list.

```cs
var res=points.Aggregate(
    (double.PositiveInfinity, new XYZ()),
    (acc, s) => acc.Item1 > origin.DistanceTo(s) 
                 ? (origin.DistanceTo(s), s) 
                 : (acc.Item1, acc.Item2),
    acc=>acc.Item2
);
```

This code works but, I don't like using Item1 or Item2 because I don't know what I am using.

Is there a way to say the first element of the tuple is named  distance and the second point.

I use this aggregate function:

```cs
Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TAccumulate, Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate>, Func<TAccumulate,TResult>)
```

and XYZ is only a type to create Point 3d.

Comment: I know it's not very relevant to the question, but why won't you just use the `Min` extensions method? I.e `points.Min(origin.DistanceTo)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give tuple elements [names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names):

```
var res = points.Aggregate(
    (DistanceTo: double.PositiveInfinity, Name2: new XYZ()),
    (acc, s) => acc.DistanceTo > origin.DistanceTo(s) 
                 ? (origin.DistanceTo(s), s) 
                 : (acc.DistanceTo, acc.Name2),
    acc => acc.Name2
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider using a specific type if the naming of the variables is important for readability

```
public class DistancePoint
{
    public double Distance{get;init;}
    public XYZ Point {get;init}
}

var res=points.Aggregate(
    new DistancePoint {Distance = double.PositiveInfinity, Point= new XYZ()},
    (acc, s) => acc.Distance > origin.DistanceTo(s) 
                 ? new DistancePoint {Distance = origin.DistanceTo(s), Point = s}
                 : acc,
    acc=>acc.Point
);
```

But yes, you can specify names of tuples if you want

```
var t = (Distance: Double.PositiveInfinity, Point: new XYZ())
```

or

```
(Double distance, XYZ point) t = (Double.PositiveInfinity, new XYZ())
```